# How to use react-bootstrap modal in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created table with some date but too better user experience I want to display it on modal. My problem is that on modal I see only first of list name and photo.
I try to do modal in component too code look more readable.

```
 const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const open = () => {
    setShow(true)
  }
return (
(..)
<thead><tr><th>miniaturka</th><th>nazwa</th><th>cena</th></tr></thead>
<tbody >
{zestawy.map((zestawy, zestaw) => {
    return(<>
 
            <tr  key={zestawy.id}>
                <th><Image src={`/nowemodule/${zestaw}.webp`} 
                width={100} height={100}/> </th>
                <td>      
<Button onClick={open}>
                    {zestawy.name} {zestawy.wielkości}</Button>
                    </td>
                <td>{cena(zestaw).toFixed(2) }zł</td>
            </tr>
<ModalPhoto
show={show} setShow={setShow}
title={zestawy.name}
content={zestawy.description}
photo={`/nowemodule/${zestaw}.webp`}
/>

        </>
    )
})}
        </tbody>
</Table>
```

and mosal.jsx

```
function ModalPhoto({title, content, photo, show, setShow}) {
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);

  return (
    <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>{title}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>

      <Modal.Body>
        <p>{content}</p>
      </Modal.Body>
<Image src={photo} width={100} height={100}/>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary">Close</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>

  );
}

export default ModalPhoto;
```

Answer (score 0):

The big problem is that you use a unique `show` state for all indexes of zestawy array. So when you set show = true, all iterations of ModalPhoto open. You only see the last one in HTML.
To fix this, you can set a showByZestawy object that contains zestawy id as key and a boolean for open or not in value :

```js
 const [showByZestawy, setShowByZestawy] = useState({});

 const handleOpen = (zestawy) => {
    setShowByZestawy({...showByZestawy, [zestawy.id]: true })
  }

 const handleClose = (zestawy) => {
    const nextShowByZestawy = {...showByZestawy};
    delete nextShowByZestawy[zestawy.id];
    setShowByZestawy(nextShowByZestawy)
  }

//...
<ModalPhoto show={showByZestawy[zestawy.id]} onHide={handleClose} />
```

You set key={zestawy.id} on `<tr>` in your map but this is an error because the  first child of your map is a Fragment that contains the Modal.
So you should do :

```js
<Fragment key={zestawy.id}> // nameless Fragments like <> cannot have a key props
  <tr>{...}</tr>
  <ModalPhoto/>
</Fragment>
```